# Remove HeaderBar gtk3 vala

Tags: header, gtk, gtk3, vala

I have such a question, can I remove 'HeaderBar'? I want to use WebKit and make my own controllers.
Perhaps it can be done like that via CssProvider?

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0V5yI.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution - window.set_decorated(false);

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to 'remove' its not the 'HeaderBar', its the window decoration. [Gtk.HeaderBar](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.HeaderBar.html) its a different thing. Window decoration is dependable of the window manager as stated in the [documentation](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Window.set_decorated.html):

> By default, windows are decorated with a title bar, resize controls,
>   etc.
>
> Some window managers allow GTK+ to disable these decorations, creating
>   a borderless window. If you set the decorated property to false using
>   this function, GTK+ will do its best to convince the window manager
>   not to decorate the window. Depending on the system, this function may
>   not have any effect when called on a window that is already visible,
>   so you should call it before calling show.
>
> On Windows, this function always works, since there’s no window
>   manager policy involved.

Although you got the right method to disable the window decoration ([Gtk.Window set_decorated(bool)](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Window.set_decorated.html)) these clarifications are needed.

Comment: I already answered, I noticed that I did not correctly ask the question.

Comment: Perhaps you should update your question or accept this answer to avoid future confusion

Comment: @AlexB indeed, maybe I'll do that if the question author does not edit it. Thanks for feedback.